# Can a non-Hound take the Ghost Hunter special ability (as Veteran)?

Tags: blades-in-the-dark, special-abilities

**ghost hunter** states.

> Your hunting pet is imbued with spirit energy. It gains potency when
> tracking or fighting the supernatural, and gains an arcane ability:
> ghost-form, mind-link, or arrow-swift. Take this ability again to
> choose an additional arcane ability for your pet.

"Your hunting pet" seems to be a prerequisite to this special ability. But, it also seems that the asset *A trained hunting pet*:

> Your animal companion obeys your commands and anticipates your
> actions. Cohort (Expert: Hunter).

is exclusive to Hounds. So, is this special ability uniquely exclusive to the Hound Playbook, or can other playbooks pick up trained pets?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### No asset is truly exclusive.

So, just to be clear:

- Anyone **can** take Ghost Hunter as a veteran advance.
- Ghost Hunter provides no special access to a hunting pet, and does nothing without one.
- Anyone can obtain a hunting pet as a permanent asset, and Ghost Hunter will work on that pet.

The game outlines the ways to **acquire a permanent asset** after the rules for spending downtime to acquire temporary assets:

> If you want to acquire an asset permanently, you can either gain it as a crew upgrade or work on it as a **long-term project** to set up a permanent acquisition.
>
> > Zamira the Whisper is a duelist and would like a *fine* sword to add to her permanent items. Her player starts a long-term project: "Get My Family Sword Back from the Pawn Shop." The GM says this is an 8-clock (she can work on it by **Consorting** or **Swaying** the pawn shop owner or maybe rolling her lifestyle level to represent small payments).
>
> -- "Downtime Activities" [from the SRD](https://bladesinthedark.com/downtime-activities)

A cohort is a standard crew upgrade, and as far as acquiring gear goes, a hunting pet is as much a signature part of kit as a *fine* weapon, so an 8-clock would probably be appropriate for picking one up.